# after space again call to autocomplete - how to do that?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

first time show result in my autocomplete serach box then selected and space again call to autocomplete how to do?

```
 <input type='text' class='btnText' id="symptomSearch" tabIndex='1' placeholder='Type words to search from repertory' onkeydown="SearchForResult(this,'RepSearch')"
                         oninput="SearchSuggestionAutocom()"/>
```

jquery:

```
  function SearchSuggestionAutocom() {
      var availablesearchSuggestion = JSON.parse(getData(cust_list.library.search.searchSuggetionWord,["12", $("#symptomSearch").val()]))
          console.log(availablesearchSuggestion);
          $( "#symptomSearch" ).autocomplete({
            source: availablesearchSuggestion.suggestions.split(',').slice(0, 5)

       });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are using wrong key word for events

Use `onBlure` instead `oninput` and `onkeydown`

```
<input type='text' class='btnText' id="symptomSearch" tabIndex='1' placeholder='Type words to search from repertory' 
                         onBlur="SearchSuggestionAutocom()"/>
```

here is [demo](https://jsbin.com/jevoyecacu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: you means oninput replace to onblur

Comment: any other solution?